# table cell shrinks when given height:100%

Tags: html, css, firefox, tablelayout

[Here is a jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/3TTES/).

As it is, in Firefox, the textarea floats in the middle of its table cell, even though it has `height:100%` and the "Top Left" cell is far bigger than it needs to be.

Uncomment the marked CSS line and run it again. The table cell, instead of expanding to use the full height of its row, has collapsed onto the textarea, dragging the `tr` down with it. You can see this in the borders.

I want the textarea and its enclosing cell to be as tall as possible, pushing the "Top Left" cell down to its smallest possible size, like this:

```
|-------------------------------------|
|Top Left        |Right               |
|----------------|x                   |
||--------------||x                   |
||lorem ipsum   ||x                   |
||              ||x                   |
||              ||x                   |
||              ||x                   |
||              ||x                   |
||              ||x                   |
||              ||x                   |
||              ||x                   |
||              ||x                   |
||              ||x                   |
||--------------||x                   |
|----------------|--------------------|
```

How do I do this? Thanks.

P.S. No javascript, and it is important that the overall height of the table be determined dynamically by the rightmost cell, and the Top Left cell's contents may wrap, so the size of the left cells can't be explicitly given.

Comment: In Chrome it looks just like you want. What browser are you seeing the described behavior in? BTW, your CSS comment syntax is wrong. Only `/* ... */` is valid.

Comment: I sincerely hope that you're just using these tables for tabular data and not for layout....

Comment: Roddy, let's please keep dogma outside of this. For certain layouts and behaviours there are NO ALTERNATIVES to tables.

Answer (score 1):

The `rowspan` messes everything...

The solution I suggest is modifying your table, removing that row span, so using two columns:

On the left one place another table with two rows, the top one for the left content, the bottom one for the `textarea`; On the right column place the Right content:

**HTML:**

```
<table border="1">
  <tr>
    <td id="w"><table id="z">
        <tr>
          <td style="height: 1px">top left</td>
        </tr>
        <tr id="x">
          <td id="y"><textarea name="textarea">lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</textarea></td>
        </tr>
      </table></td>
    <td>Right
      <ul>
        <li>x</li>
        <li>x</li>
        <li>x</li>
        <li>x</li>
        <li>x</li>
        <li>x</li>
        <li>x</li>
        <li>x</li>
        <li>x</li>
        <li>x</li>
        <li>x</li>
        <li>x</li>
        <li>x</li>
        <li>x</li>
        <li>x</li>
        <li>x</li>
        <li>x</li>
        <li>x</li>
      </ul></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

**CSS:**

```
td {
   vertical-align: top;        
}
textarea
{
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}

#x, #y, #z, #w
{
     height: 100%;
}
```

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/3TTES/46/

Comment: Thanks. I will accept this (reluctantly) if nothing else comes up, but a generalised, rowspan-friendly solution is what I'm really after.

Answer (score 0):

This is not the perfect solution but ...

You need to tell table it's height so it's diffent than auto.

So your css for the fiddle would like this

```
textarea, table, #x, #y
{
    height: 100%; 
}
```

The problem is that the browser now uses it's own logic to set the height of the cells and you can't override it with "height", so the top-left cell is quite large.

```
#z { height:1px; }
```

Even if you set it to 1px it still does it's own calculation ...

Link to the fiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/c7GNc/

Comment: This doesn't meet the constraint that the bottom cell must be `pushing the "Top Left" cell down to its smallest possible size`.